# F1 to B1/B2 in the USA, without having studied in the USA

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I got a students visa, F1 for the USA, for an additional MBA. I went to the USA and since I was not really happy with what I went through, I decided to come back. The college had given fake commitments and I didn't want to do college-hopping. I came back within a span of 1 month, i.e. I went in Dec 2015 and came back in Jan. 2016. 
Since I am a working professional, I don't intend to pursue studies in the USA anymore. 
My F1 visa was granted in July 15, for a term of 5 years. 
Can I apply for a Visitors Visa now for the USA? Or will it get rejected since I didn't study there?
What would be the process, if anyone could help?

Comment: Was it the "University of Northern New Jersey"?

Comment: Nope. MCNY. NYC.

Answer (score 6):

You certainly can apply for a B1/B2 visa, which shouldn't be affected by your decision to withdraw from the university. When you did that, it was reported to SEVIS, and you left the US, as you were required to do. Your F-1 visa is now invalid. That you decided not to pursue your education in the United States would have no bearing on visiting the country.

You proceed just as you did for the F-1, and start by consulting the instructions on the website of the US Embassy or Consulate where you will apply.

Comment: Gives me a great relief. I was told by people here that I can never visit the USA again.

Comment: @Eevie let me get this straight, you got anxious because random strangers told you can't visit but got relieved because another random stranger told you can...? Understand please that we are just random people on the Internet and while we strive to help we are not the USCIS.

Comment: Dude, atleast I can try to get a B2.